# ADO.Net - Truncate Column Data When DataRow is Added to DataTable

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

This is my first post on Stackoverflow.

I am reading millions of rows from a flat file (comma delimited) and iterating each read row and then each column of each row.  The iteration of each column is to allow user defined conversions, defaults, removal of special characters, etc. to be performed.  The current implementation is very efficient.

The reading of the data is done in batches of 20k.  When I'm processing a read row, I issue a NewRow() call on my in-memory DataTable.  I then start iterating each column to scrub their values.  I'm trying to minimize as much as I can when I'm processing a rows columns.

My problem is this.  If the value (text in this case) that is read from the flat file is longer than the MaxLength of the targeted DataTables DataColumn, I receive an exception stating such when I issue the following:

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Is there a way to tell ADO.Net (or my in-memory DataTable) to truncate the data instead of complaining?

Again, I can easily add logic in the loop to do this check/truncation for me, but those things add up when you're dealing with millions of rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();

...
...

if(YourText.Length < ColumnMaxLength)
{
  newRow["YourLimitedColumnName"] = YourText;
}
else
{
  newRow["YourLimitedColumnName"] = YourText.Substring(0, ColumnMaxLength);
}

...
...

dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Comment: Thanks @Davide.  I certainly could - but, I'm looking for an option that's inherent in ADO.Net to keep from writing something like that.  Major driver in not doing this is the fact that I'm processing so many rows of data.